# Why iRedMail only works for few hours on my machine on EC2?

Tags: email, amazon-ec2

I have installed the latest version of iRedMail on my VM on EC2 (ubuntu 14.04) and it works perfectly fine for the first few hours. After that, I can not send and receive any emails from/to my VM. I have already submitted the form to Amazon to remove the the Email limitations.
Any hints/helps is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a t(1/2).micro instance?

Comment: Yes I do use t2.micro

Answer (score 1):

I found a filtering rule in the main.cf causes that. I remove the filters and it perfectly worked.